# Is there any "truly" uncountably infinitely generated cone?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-analysis

Given a set $U$ in $\Bbb R^n$, a conical hull, or a generated cone is defined as

> $\text{cone}⁡(U)=\{∑_{i∈I}λ_i{\bf v}_i:\{{\bf v}_i\}_{i∈I}⊆U,λ_i≥0,|I|<+∞\}$.

If $U$ is finite, then $\text{cone}⁡(U)$ is called a finitely generated cone. There is countably infinitely generated cone, e.g.

> [image]

My question is, is there any uncountably infinitely generated cone? Or in the contrary, is the following statement true or false?

> For every $\text{cone}⁡(U)$ for some uncountable set $U$, there must be at most countable subset $U'\subseteq U$ s.t. $\text{cone}⁡(U') = \text{cone}⁡(U)$? A proof or a counterexample is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The last cone in your picture is not countably generated. The points on the boundary can only be generated as multiples of points on the boundary  (I hope you understand what I mean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dominik says in the comments, the round cone is not finitely generated; it's generated from the uncountable set
$$U = \{(\cos \theta, \sin\theta, 1)\,\vert\,\theta\in [0,2\pi)\}.$$

For any $u_i\in U$, you cannot represent $u_i$ as a finite positive combination of vectors in $\operatorname{cone}(U)\setminus \{u_i\}.$ To see this, suppose for contradiction that $u_i  = (\cos \theta_i, \sin\theta_i, 1) = \sum_{j} \lambda_j u_j.$ Then
$$0 = (\cos\theta_i, \sin\theta_i, -1)\cdot u_i = \sum_j \lambda_j\left[\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)-1\right] < 0.$$